# Sublime Text 2 - Open folders

Tags: editor, sublimetext2, sublimetext

Is it possible to open multiple folders in the same window using **Sublime Text 2**?

Selecting `File->Open Folder` always opens the folder in a new window.

Sublime Text is an excellent editor, but this issue is a bit annoying.

Comment: For those struggling with this same issue, it is possible to drag and drop a folder onto the folders panel. I, however, am looking for a way open the folder through sublime interface e.g. via the File menu

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can use the `Add folder to Project...` item on the `Project` menu to open a folder in the current **Sublime Text 2** window.

*With Sublime Text 2, a project is always open, even if it is anonymous and unsaved.*

Comment: is there a way to view the folder's internal file structure (like in brackets) once opened?

Answer (score 5):

In Sublime text 3, you can just drag and drop folders, it will open multiple folders. However i have not tried it in Sublime text 2.

**Update:**

Drag and drop works in Sublime text 2 as well.

Comment: Works in sublime text2

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell, this behavior is built in. In `Packages/Default/Main.sublime-menu`, the listing for `Open Folder…` is

```json
{ "command": "prompt_open_folder", "caption": "Open Folder…", "platform": "!OSX" }
```

Unfortunately, after searching all through the installation, there's no macro or `.py` file with the `prompt_open_folder` command, so it must be a hard-coded part of the binary, which makes sense, because it's a system call to the operating system/window manager to open a file picker dialog.

It should be relatively straightforward to write a plugin to select a folder for inclusion in the current window, but unfortunately I'm not quite able to at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS users, use the command 'open' like so:

> `usr@mac ~ $ open -a "Sublime-text" "./Desktop/GitHub/uoe"`

This will open all the folders in the 'uoe' directory in sublime provided you are at the root directory. For windows/Linux try finding something similar to 'open' :)